# Dynamically place elements in a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on creating a function that can help me dynamically create something like this: [Emotion Wheel](http://www.mikhailthomas.com/emotionwheel.html)

That is a manual mock up of what I'm trying to create dynamically. I want to pass into the function the number of axis and the number of "nodes" per half-axis. My biggest issue is figuring out placement and how to work that out. I'm still working on some rough draft stuff, but I was curious if there was something I was missing/hint on making it easier, or if I'd essentially just need to break down and dig up my Trig knowledge and come up with something from there.

Comment: could you show your code? maybe a *jsfiddle*

Comment: Right now its all manually placed, so I can show my code, but the code I have written doesn't pertain to placement or creation, simply just the hover/click effects.